# ProcessStartInfo arguments

Tags: c#, processstartinfo

I have a process, which takes some arguments. I want it to start from C#. I have tried the same arguments in shortcut and it works. On the other hand, in c# it doesnt, so here are the arguments. The argument format is correct, but i get a wrong argument error at -k

```
ProcessStartInfo prf = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\" + "argstest.exe");       
prf.UseShellExecute =true;
prf.Arguments = "-l http://test.tes1:testa@testb.testing.com:3333/ -k testing TYPE=0 USER=1 COUNT=10";
Process.Start(prf);
```

Process starts, but closes instantly, because the -k argument which should be testing doesnt get sent to program.
I have tried adding a " " space before -l but same, also tried @" -l ..."

Comment: And where is your non working C# code?

Comment: It doesn't work is not helpful. Tell us more. Tell us how it fails. Show the rest of your code.

Comment: Well, process exits because he doesnt get the -k argument which should be testing.

Comment: Rather than drip feeding us in comments, edit the question and fix it.

Comment: Tested your code and there's nothing wrong with it. The problem must be in your application when you are parsing your arguments.

Comment: How come it works when i start it from shortcut?

Comment: Here I'll post the code I used in an answer and you can look at it yourself and possibly figure out what is wrong.

Comment: A little remark: to create path from string a better way is:
`Path.Combine(@"C:\","argstest.exe")`

Comment: Have you tried to run a process with parameters from the command prompt (cmd.exe)? What's the result?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in arguments parameter. Like this:

```
prf.Arguments = @"-l http://test.tes1:testa@testb.testing.com:3333/ -k testing TYPE=0 USER=1 COUNT=10";
```

Comment: @user1422473 Please, post some more C# code (edit a question). We need to see lines, where you start a process. Maybe a problem is there.

Comment: There is no character or escape sequence that changes meaning when using a verbatim string, so it would be quite surprising that this change alone would make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and did not find any issues. Perhaps you find this useful in tracking down your problem, I did this and you can do the same:

The Console App that you are trying to run, I did this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

From another console app, just this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo prf = new ProcessStartInfo("ConsoleApplication1.exe");
            prf.UseShellExecute = true;
            prf.Arguments = "-l http://test.tes1:testa@testb.testing.com:3333/ -k testing TYPE=0 USER=1 COUNT=10";
            Process.Start(prf);
        }
```

The output:

```
-1
http://test.tes1:testa@testb.testing.com:3333/
-k
testing
TYPE=0
USER=1
COUNT=10
```

This is what leads me to believe the problem isn't on the Process.Start() side, but in the way that your other app is parsing the arguments. As for why the shortcut works and this doesn't, maybe you should copy/paste the shortcut that you are using, not really sure on that one.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found that works best for this is to set it up with an escaped quote around your command, like so:

```
string command = "ping -c 4 google.com";

ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", "-c " + "\"" + command + "\"");
```